# Move li to the right in menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a menu, and I would like to have the last 3 options (some images for Facebook/Twiter/Gmail) to be aligned to the right. So far I tried:
`li:last-child { float:right;}`- combine the 3 images in one to have the last option to the right, but not even so works
`float: right;` - the same result as above
`text-align: right;` - no change

```css
#nav { 
    background-color: #e26a63;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: FONT;
    font-size: 20px;
}
   
#wrap {
    padding-left: 60px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: bottom;

}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 225px; 
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #cb5f59;
}

#nav ul li:after {
  content: "";
  font-size: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 5px;

}
#nav ul li:hover:after {
  background: #9e4a45;
}
#nav ul ul li:hover:after {
  background: transparent;
}
#nav ul li a, visited {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #e26a63;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
        z-index: 10;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
 <div id="wrap">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li><li>
        <a href="#">Study</a></li><li>
        <a href="#">Games</a>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Riddles</a></li><li> 
                <a href="#">Flip card game</a></li><li>  
                <a href="#">Spot the mistake</a></li><li> 
                <a href="#">Multiple choice</a></li>             
            </ul>
          </li><li>
        <a href="read.html">Read</a></li><li>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li><li>
        <a href="about.html">About Us</a></li><li id="alignright">
        FB
        </li><li>
            Twitter
        </li><li style="text-align: right;">
            Gmail
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'd be better of using two `ul`'s and floating one right.

Comment: You shouldnt be using an 'id' twice on the same page.

Comment: @Dov Benyomin Sohacheski I forgot to delete those, but thanks for observation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

```
#nav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.alignright { float: right; }
```

Comment: It seems to work, but those options go off screen to the right, and my options for the menu jump to the top, instead of remaining at the bottom of the wrap.

Comment: Because they have no padding, as normal links, put All of these 3 in <a> and it will look ok.

Comment: Normally all items (as inline-blocks) are aligned by font baseline, float disturbs that inline flow.

Comment: And how am I supposed to have 3 different links in one <a?

Comment: Just wrap <li> contents (each link in each <li> as <a>). 
`<li style="float:right"><a>Gmail</a></li>
<li style="float:right"><a>Sth</a></li>
<li style="float:right"><a>Sth else</a></li>`

Comment: That float: right doesn't do anything to move the options to right at all.

Comment: Have you added styles that I wrote in answer above? (#nav is crucial?)

Comment: Oh, I deleted that one and forgot to put it now back again. Thank you very much for your solution, as it works perfect. Can't up vote your answer, but I can say thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that:

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/jjp6zx0c/)

```css
#nav {
  background-color: #e26a63;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: FONT;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#wrap {
  height: 100px;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
#nav ul li {} #nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #cb5f59;
}
#nav ul li:after {
  content: "";
  font-size: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
}
#nav ul li:hover:after {
  background: #9e4a45;
}
#nav ul ul li:hover:after {
  background: transparent;
}
#nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: .5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #e26a63;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
}
#nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}
#alignright {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <div id="wrap">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Study</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Games</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Riddles</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Flip card game</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Spot the mistake</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Multiple choice</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="read.html">Read</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li id="alignright">
        FB
      </li>
      <li>
        Twitter
      </li>
      <li style="text-align: right;">
        Gmail
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I could do this before too, but it's about the layout I'm concerned about. Your solution is good, works, but now the menu is messed up. The alignment isn't like before.

Comment: The general method is correct, a few tweaks of the styling is all that it would take to get it back to the way you want. I'll leave that to you, this is only for demo purposes.